# Nginx - Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME type & [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]

Tags: css, docker, nginx, mime-types

Using Nginx, I'm switching over from XAMPP to Docker and now my css files that worked perfectly in XAMPP doesn't work here. The error messages I received in FireFox console is:

```
The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

I'm trying to include the mime.types but it isn't working. I added location ~ .css and location ~ .js and now I get:

```
GET http://localhost/main.css   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
```

Folder:

```
app/public
   index.php
   main.css
php/
   Dockerfile

nginx/conf.d
     default.conf
     mime.types

docker-compose.yaml
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
     web:
           image: nginx:latest
           ports:
                 - "80:80"
volumes:
  - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
app:
build: 
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
volumes: 
  - ./app:/app
```

default.conf.d

```
server {
include    mime.types;
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /app/public;
index index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
    location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

}

mime.types

```
types {
text/html                             html htm shtml;
text/css                              css;
text/xml                              xml rss;
image/gif                             gif;
image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
application/x-javascript              js;
text/plain                            txt;
text/x-component                      htc;
text/mathml                           mml;
image/png                             png;
image/x-icon                          ico;
image/x-jng                           jng;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
application/java-archive              jar war ear;
application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
application/pdf                       pdf;
application/x-cocoa                   cco;
application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
application/x-makeself                run;
application/x-perl                    pl pm;
application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
application/x-sea                     sea;
application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
application/x-stuffit                 sit;
application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
application/zip                       zip;
application/octet-stream              deb;
application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
application/octet-stream              dmg;
application/octet-stream              eot;
application/octet-stream              iso img;
application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;
audio/mpeg                            mp3;
audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
video/quicktime                       mov;
video/x-flv                           flv;
video/x-msvideo                       avi;
video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
video/x-mng                           mng;
}
```